# $geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-indexes

Add schema.index({startlocation: '2dsphere'}) in schema but not able to clear the error.
schema
tourSchema.index({ startLocation: '2dsphere' }); --> this line is add in model

controller

```
exports.getDistances = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const { latlng, unit } = req.params;
const [lat, lng] = latlng.split(',');

const multiplier = unit === 'mi' ? 0.000621371 : 0.001;

if (!lat || !lng) {
next(
  new AppError(
    'Please provide latitutr and longitude in the format lat,lng.',
    400
  )
);
}
const distances = await Tour.aggregate([
{
  $geoNear: {
    near: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [lng * 1, lat * 1],
    },
    distanceField: 'distance',
    distanceMultiplier: multiplier,
    spherical: true,
  },
},
{
  $project: {
    distance: 1,
    name: 1,
  },
},
]);

 res.status(200).json({
 status: 'success',
 data: {
  data: distances,
 },
 });
 });
```

"error":
    "message": "$geoNear requires a 2d or 2dsphere index, but none were found",

I am getting this error, please help me out with this. 
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're watching Jona's node Course. I had the same problem. You should go back to MongoDb Compass, remove the index, and then copy this code:

```js
tourSchema.index({
    startLocation: "2dsphere",
})
```

Then restart the server and check in MongoDb Compass that your index is `GEOSPATIAL`. After that, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same course and got the same issue. Adding the index manually in mongoDB gave me some insight

```
> db.tours.createIndex({ startLocation: "2dsphere" })
```

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Index build failed: daf8a8c6-a580-4913-8732-5fbb7b5641b0: Collection natours.tours ( 4840d817-5cdb-4d5e-91ff-543cd26824ad ) :: caused by :: Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('61542fdbbab94c9f1075336d'), startLocation: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [] }, ratingsAverage: 4.8, ratingsQuantity: 1, images: [], createdAt: new Date(1632907215605), startDates: [], secretTour: false, guides: [], name: \"New Test Tour\", duration: 5, maxGroupSize: 25, difficulty: \"easy\", price: 397, summary: \"Breathtaking hike through the Canadian Banff National Park\", imageCover: \"tour-1-cover.jpg\", location: [], slug: \"new-test-tour\", __v: 0 }  Point must only contain numeric elements",
    "code" : 16755,
    "codeName" : "Location16755"
}
```

In this case, I've created a tour without any coordinates and the 2dsphere index couldn't be created. Removing this wrongfully tour solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if none of this works then you can simply go to mongodb compass and follow these below steps:

1. go to your tours
2. and on index section
3. click on create an index fill the popup create index as on below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UijAG.png

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that all the tours in the mongodb have geolocation data that will be used when calculating distances.
2. If the error persist add the startLoction index directly from the mongodb compass.
   [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NKJj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this error is actually Jonas provided us a pre build data of tours, in all that data there are a location field which is not empty generally this error is occurs when your location field is empty array make sure that your location array is not empty and please try to work with Jonas's provided tours data do not add your own tour and if you add your own tour make sure your location array should not be empty otherwise you will face this error even you added index in your tour model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- I faced with the same error and fixed it by removing all tours
  (documents) with empty locations from `DB`. It will unblocks DB to
  set index properly.
- After deleting index will be set automatically with restarting `app (server).`